# How to access Sinatra Session from a module

Tags: session, sinatra, ruby-1.9

I am developing an application with Ruby 1.9.2 and Sinatra 1.3.
I have a helper module that needs to access session data. 
Here is a snippet of my module

```
require 'sinatra'

module SessionHelper

  def current_user
    session['current_user']
  end

end
```

This works fine with ruby 1.8.7, but when I run the application with Ruby 1.9.2, I get an error saying: `undefined local variable or method 'session' for SessionHelper:Module`

Answer (score 2):

try something like this:

```
require 'sinatra/base'

module Sinatra
  module SessionHelper
    def current_user
      session['current_user']
    end
  end
  register current_user
end
```

Then in your controllers somewhere, you could do this:

```
user = current_user
```

Take a look at the documentation on [writing Sinatra extensions](http://www.sinatrarb.com/extensions.html) - it applies to other custom modules too.

Hope that helps!